DeviceCheckProvider is not available on this platform
I'm trying to implement Firebase AppCheck on iOS. I'm getting this error:
10.25.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed: 
'The operation couldn’t be completed. 
The attestation provider DeviceCheckProvider is not supported on current platform and OS version.'

This is confusing to me because my iOS version should be sufficient, and I shouldn't be even attempting to use DeviceCheck because AppAttest is tried first.
What I've tried so far:

flutter clean; flutter pub get; pod install

Isolated the problem to Apple servers; this doesn't happen on production without AppCheck, or using an emulator.

I've completed all the steps in the docs: Debugging

I've logged the iOS and platform version, just to be sure:
flutter: Device System: iOS 17.5, iPhone 15 iPhone


I've made sure every single pod package has iOS deployment version 13.0, which is higher than the minimum for DeviceCheck (11.0).
The knobs I feel like I can turn are

Made sure the AppAttest capability is set in my Apple developer account

Made sure the AppAttest capability is set in my Xcode project

-FIRDebugEnabled launch option in Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

Setting AppAttest environment to production in iOS Entitlements file, disabling -FIRDebugEnabled flag, and using AppleProvider.appAttestWithDeviceCheckFallback (since not in debug mode anymore)

Double-checked GoogleService-Info.plist


This is the code I'm using to initialize AppCheck, executed right after Firebase is initialized:
// init Firebase App Check
  AndroidProvider androidProvider =
      kDebugMode ? AndroidProvider.debug : AndroidProvider.playIntegrity;
  AppleProvider iosAppCheckProvider = kDebugMode
      ? AppleProvider.debug
      : AppleProvider.appAttestWithDeviceCheckFallback;
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
      androidProvider: androidProvider, appleProvider: iosAppCheckProvider);

i.e. if debug mode, use debug app check provider.
